# Element value via array's address

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main()
{
    char ar1[4][6] = {
        { 'P', 'e', 't', 'e', 'r' },
        { 'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'n', 'y' },
        { 'M', 'a', 'r', 'y' },
        { 'K', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'y' }
    };
    char *ar2;
    char *ar3[2];

    ar2 = &ar1[1][1];
    ar3[0] = &ar1[0][0];
    ar3[1] = &ar1[1][0];
    printf("Output5 = %s\n", &ar1[1][4]);
    printf("Output6 = %s\n", ar2-3);
    printf("Output7 = %s\n", ar3[0]+1);
    printf("Output8 = %s\n", ar3[1]+2);
}
```

Results:

```
printf("Output5 = %s\n", &ar1[1][4]); 
Output 5 = myMary
```

I understand it starts printing a string from element `[1][4]` but why does it stop at `y` which happens to be element `[2][3]`?

```
printf("Output6 = %s\n", ar2-3);
Output 6 = r
```

How do we even get this?

```
printf("Output7 = %s\n", ar3[0]+1);
Output 7 = eter
```

Given `ar3[0] = &ar1[0][0];` ar3[0]+1 means therefore we start at ar[0][1]. But now we end at `r`, element `[0][4]` which is the last element of the row.

```
    Output 8 = hnnyMary
```

Given `ar3[1] = &ar1[1][0];` ar3[1]+2 means we start at ar[1][2]. But now instead of ending at the last element of it's row, we now end at last element of row 2.

Anyone can explain to me what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no partial initialization in C.

When you do

```
char ar1[4][6] = {
    { 'P', 'e', 't', 'e', 'r' },
    { 'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'n', 'y' },
    { 'M', 'a', 'r', 'y' },
    { 'K', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'y' }
};
```

all elements of `ar1` are initialized, with `'\0'` in the absence of a different value.

`ar1[0][0]` is initialized with `'P'`, ..., `ar1[0][4]` is initialized with `'r'`, `ar1[0][5]` is initialized with `'\0'`, `ar1[1][0]` is initialized with `'J'`, ... `ar1[1][5]` is initialized with `'y'`, `ar1[2][0]` is initialized with `'M'`, ..., `ar1[2][4]` is initialized with `'\0'`, `ar1[2][5]` is initialized with `'\0'`, ...

The string beginning at `ar1[1][4]` is `"nyMary"`.

Comment: I don't think it necessarily has to be filled in with nulls, could be anything.

Comment: Oh. I learn something today. I didn't know `\0` would be filled in.

Comment: @theSmallNothing it must use `0` (of the proper king) to fill unspecified elements in an **initialization**. It can be anything if you leave the whole object uninitialized. `int a[1000] = {42};` sets 1 element to `42` and 999 elements to `0` but `int a[1000]; a[0] = 42;` has 999 elements with garbage.

Comment: @pmg OK, that makes sense, I wasn't sure with brace initialization. (proper king?)

Comment: @theSmallNothing I meant proper "proper kind" :)

Answer (score 0):

Result 1: `{ 'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', 'n', 'y' },` this fills the entire `6` elements, leaving no space for the null character: therefore, the complete string is taken from index [1][4] (`n` - second row, fifth element) till it encounters the first `\0`, which is encountered after `y` in `Mary`.

Result 2: `ar2` is at index [1][1], i.e., at `o`, second row, second element. `ar2-1`= `J`, `ar2-2=\0`, `ar2-3=r`

Result 3: `ar[3][0]=P`, so `ar[3][0]+1=e`, the next element, and since it is a string, it starts printing from `e` to first null character, after `r`.

Result 4: `ar[3][1]=J`, `ar[3][1]+2=h`, the next to next element, again it being a string, is printed till the first null character (after `y`).